# Which OAuth providers are widely used over the world?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0

I'm busy with identifying my website's users via single sign on OAuth providers.
The key is email, so I would like to get a list here of services who provides email.

Twitter, viadeo, linkedin doesn't gives email even with granted access to user's details.

Right now, I'm ok for facebook and live ID.

Which other services based on OAuth are used ??

Comment: A google search is probably more appropriate than a question here

Comment: tohhhhhhhhhhh ! I've searched the web, but here in france, I don't know which service a guy in middle of nowhere in arizona uses to login on his favorite websites !

Comment: I disagree with downvoting the question. People come to SE for expertise they can't get from a Google search. Maybe you could, you know, provide a URL if you think Google will do the trick? I have the same question and searching google brought me here. Now I have the start of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going after big companies may be a good idea...

- Google has a lot of services used by many people, there are also companies using google apps and all their employees have a valid google account! => They provide oAuth
- Microsoft has MSN Live, a few years ago it's predecessor Instante
  Messenger was included in Windows, also used by many people! => They
  provide oAuth
- Facebook has 845 million monthly active users and 483 million daily
  active users users => They provide oAuth

I would go after these three as they're big players on their areas and all of them provide oAuth.

Comment: Thanks silvio, this was the kind of response I was expecting. Right now my webapp allow facebook, windows live id (new name of msn ?) and google account via openid. I hope some others will add some

Answer (score 0):

I would say the important ones are facebook, google, yahoo and maybe myopenid